# Ajax форма перезагружает страницу

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт для обработки формы. Почему-то после отправки данных страница перезагружается. 
вот такой скрипт.

```
 $(function() {
          $('#fetch-report').submit(function(e) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var $form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
              type: $form.attr('method'),
              contentType : false,
              processData : false,
              url: $form.attr('action'),
              data: $form.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
              console.log('success');
            }).fail(function() {
              console.log('fail');
            });
            //отмена действия по умолчанию для кнопки submit
            e.preventDefault(); 
          });
        });
```

код форы

```
<form action="<%=Constants.LINK_INTERNAL_PREFIX %>reports/fetch/<%=entry.get("id") %>" method="POST"
                    class="form-inline-report col-md-8" id="fetch-report" 
                    enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="call()">
```

.....

```
<input value="Send" type="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Кажется тут опечатка. Посмотрите на id формы и на селектор которым вы эту форму находите

Comment: исправил, но проблема осталась.

Comment: эта функция не прописана, убрал ее. все равно страница перезагружается.

Comment: да запрос отправляется, ошибок в консоли нету. отправка работает. использую мозилу,  в ней тестирую.

Comment: я бы с радостью но на работе у меня эта функция заблокирована.((

Comment: подскажите, в каком месте стоит искать косяк?

Comment: Если этот скрипт по работе, то дайте люлей работодателю за то, что он блокирует ресурсы, необходимые для работы :)

Comment: в отделе + 1300к человек)) не думаю что я успею поставить блок=)

Comment: Да. "Заблокировано фильтром URL" сервис McAFee.

Comment: Тогда стОит потихоньку чистить комментарии, пока тут чат устраиваем

Comment: Запрос точно отправляется ajax'ом? Как вы это проверяли?

Comment: а как это можно проверить, я не представляю. по идее правила заполнения формы, тип запроса, ссылка и пр. это и есть ajax

Comment: 1. Можно увидеть в Devtools->Network (запрос помечается как XHR), 2. Можно увидеть на стороне сервера по заголовку `X-Requested-With`, 3 Можно вписать перед отправкой ajax какой-нибудь `alert('AJAX');`... Наверняка еще варианты придумать можно

Comment: Мне что-то кажется что не отправляется у вас ajax, а просто отправляется форма. И, возможно, виноваты в этом две строки `event....`. Напишите после `$(function() {` `'use strict';` - скорее всего получите ошибку

Comment: Исправилась ситуация?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте e.preventDefault(); перед началом  $.ajax. У меня самого иногда ajax форма перезагружается, вот тоже ищу источник проблемы)